# Dempster-Shafer theory initial belief values

Tags: probability-theory

I am looking to implement D-S Theory in my (computer science) research, I'll be using it to determine the probability that a triggered sensor event is a true positive.

How would you calculate an initial belief value without having the ability to perform data mining on a dataset (a cold start)?

One solution that has been postulated is to use the manufactures performance statistics that the sensors are working correctly and then adjust this over time to take account for false positives. Although this will result is a very high initial belief rate for some sensors (95% belief).

Comment: Why is this not a mathematics question?

Comment: I assumed it was fine here as it was being applied in a computer science context.

Comment: Then please make this connection; it's not visible in your post as it is now.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was implied when referring to data mining approaches.

Comment: There are DST questions on Cross-Validated too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 95% (initial) belief corresponds to the probability of a true positive according to the performance statistics, then that seems appropriate to me.